# How do you set a variable global in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates

Note: Ive already set mine to extend to a base controller extending the ci controller for all my controller, the problem is how do i pass and declare a variable and pass it on the template?

Comment: nevermind it seems i can set it in the constructor

Comment: You can follow the this link `https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-global-variable/`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to view file from controller as below :

Home.php Controller file

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Title";
        $data['heading'] = "Heading";

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

home.php view file

```
<html>
  <head>
          <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 difftent methods view data from the controller.

**Method 1 :**

Controller file : Home.php

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = "Title";
        $this->data['heading'] = "Heading";

        $this->load->view('home', $this->data);
    }

}
```

**Method 2 :**

Controller file : Home.php

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Title";
        $data['heading'] = "Heading";

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }

}
```

**Note : View file same here. no changes**

view file : home.php

```
enter code here
<html>
  <head>
          <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```